# Unresolved import with npm React portlet with Liferay ce 7.0

Tags: reactjs, liferay, portlet

So, my goal is to learn to create Liferay portlet using React in framework development. I have follewed [instructions](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/npm-react-portlet-template)  and used maven to build my project

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.liferay \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=com.liferay.project.templates.npm.react.portlet \
-DgroupId=com.liferay \
-DartifactId=my-npm-react-portlet \
-Dpackage=com.liferay.npm.react \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-DclassName=MyNpmReactPortlet \
-DpackageJsonVersion=1.0.0
```

Proplem now occures when I am deploying my freshy made portlet. Server doesnt print anything else to console than processing my-npm-react-portlet-1.0.jar

I have checked my modules with Blade sh lb and blade sh diag and outcome is:

```
 Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.frontend.js.loader.modules.extender.npm; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"
```

Project bnd.bnd

```
Bundle-Name: my-npm-react-portlet <br/>
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.liferay.npm.react <br/>
Bundle-Version: 1.0 <br>
Export-Package: com.liferay.npm.react.constants <br/>
Web-ContextPath: /my-npm-react-portlet <br/>
-jsp: *.jsp,*.jspf <br/>
-plugin.jsp: com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin <br/>
-plugin.npm: com.liferay.ant.bnd.npm.NpmAnalyzerPlugin <br/>
-plugin.resourcebundle: <br/>com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin <br/>
-plugin.sass: com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin <br/>
-sass: *
Bundle-Name: my-npm-react-portlet
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.liferay.npm.react
Bundle-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: com.liferay.npm.react.constants
Web-ContextPath: /my-npm-react-portlet
-jsp: *.jsp,*.jspf
-plugin.jsp: com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.npm: com.liferay.ant.bnd.npm.NpmAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.resourcebundle: com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.sass: com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin
-sass: *
```

And last pom.xml (code block doesn't want to work with this one).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-npm-react-portlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.frontend.js.loader.modules.extender</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.util.taglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/META-INF/resources/**/.sass-cache/</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.liferay.ant.bnd</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.41</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.liferay.css.builder</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <docrootDirName>src/main/resources</docrootDirName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I will appreciate any help according this proplem!

Comment: it seems that the module com.liferay.frontend.js.loader.modules.extender, that you are using as dependency is not exporting its packages https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0.x/modules/apps/foundation/frontend-js/frontend-js-loader-modules-extender/bnd.bnd, so this package you can't import is private and you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on a Gradle, bnd Liferay module. I ran into similar unresolved requirement issues. I am not sure if this will help you or applies to your issue.

In my case, I found that the bnd.bnd file needs the import statements to be in the exact specific format. I am guessing it applies to the export statements as well. If not in this format, there is no error but there are deployment/run time issues like yours.

The following with commas, * and \ worked for me, rather than multiple import statements. I ran into this information buried on the Liferay forums. I don't remember the exact post that helped me.

```
Import-Package: \
com.xyz.core.api, \
com.xyz..core.api.model, \
com.liferay.portal.kernel.*, \
*
```

Here is the bnd documentation in case it helps:
http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/390-wrapping.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018156951-Resolving-a-Plugin-s-Dependencies#understanding-excluded-jars

this article is also helpful to solve the issue.